# How to update bottom TabBar without doing the navigation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, stack, tabbar

I have an app with a `HomeView` and a bottom `TabBar` which load other views on tap. On this `TabBar` bar I also have a More button which on click opens a listView, each cell of this view also opens other views. (When I'm talking about views, I mean new tunnels/navigation controllers are displayed for example: MyPicturesViewController, SettingsViewController etc...).
There is my problem, I have to implement a feature that from my `HomeView` on a button click it navigates to a specific view that is not on the `TabBar` but in the More list and also update the `TabBar` to highlight the More button.

I tried at first to navigate manually with this code:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard.instantiate(NewViewController.self)
self.viewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

it works pretty well
and then update the tabbar manually

```
self.viewController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4
```

But updating the `TabBar` redirect automatically to the selected index which is the More list view and don't even take in count the manual navigation I did in the previous code.
So my question is, is it possible to update `TabBar` bar without loading its own `navigationcontroller?` If not how can I achieve what I want to do, I tried many things such as create a `navigationcontroller` and its viewcontrollers and replace the tabbar viewcontrollers stacks but I didn't succeed.

Thank you in advance for those who will take time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Instead doing it before

```
self.viewController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4
```

Push your controller in tabBar delegate method

```
  func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController == desiredNavigationController {
            show(desiredNavigationController, animated: true) // push
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with your method the tabBar disappear after the show, I need the tabbar to stay and be updated and at the same time the desiredViewController to be displayed

Comment: push in the current navigation controller will not hide your tab bar